# Swift LongPressGestureRecognizer on NavigationBar

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8, xcode6, uinavigationbar

I have an `UINavigationBar` and I have an `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` which should be activated when I press within a certain rectangle on the screen after holding 0.7 seconds. My problem now is: I want to have the GestureRecognizer activated when I tap on the title of my NavigationBar. But the tap isn't recognized on the navigationBar - every point outside of the navigationBar is detected. How can I make this work? Help would be great :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem. You need to add GestureRecognizer on UINavigationBar. Here is my example:

```
class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    var longPressRecognizer : UILongPressGestureRecognizer? = nil

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressAction")
        self.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer!)
    }

    func longPressAction() {
        NSLog("action")
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer I'll try that out later. Just to get sure: Isn't it more elegant to use ! when initializing the GestureRecognizer instead of making it optional and initialize it with nil?